# MvxCollectionViewCell blues

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a `UICollectionView` inheriting from `MvxViewController`. It contains cells inheriting from `MvxCollectionViewCell`. The data is bound to the source through *CreateBindingSet()* in `UICollectionView` and I use *DelayBind()* to bind the data to the Cell when it's instantiated.

I've subclassed `MvxCollectionViewSource` and overridden *`GetOrCreateCellFor()`* method. Now whenever I load the data, the dequed cells retain old data.

I've considered 2 options:

1. Create a new Cell in GetOrCreateCellFor() method. It fails because I need to pass an IntPtr in the constructor and I can't create no-arg ctor due to the contract with MvxCollectionViewCell.
2. Update bindings when the Cell is displayed during `WillDisplayCell()`. This doesn't work and the old data is shown.

Any way out of this?

Edit: Added code

-- ViewWillAppear of MyView : MvxViewController

```
public class MyView : MvxViewController{
    // other stuff
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        var sourceOne = new MyCollectionViewSource (MyCollectionView, new NSString ("MyCollectionViewCell"));
        MyCollectionView.Source = sourceOne;
        var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel> ();

        bindings.Bind (sourceOne)
                .To (vm => vm.ItemList);

        bindings.Apply ();
        MyCollectionView.ReloadData ();
    }
}
```

-- MyCollectionViewSource : MvxCollectionViewSource

```
public MyCollectionViewSource : MvxCollectionViewSource{
protected override UICollectionViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            return collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (new NSString ("MyCollectionViewCell"), indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell;
        }
public override void WillDisplayCell (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cellz = cell as MyCollectionViewCell;
            cellz.ClearAllBindings ();
            cellz.BindUrl ();
    }
}
```

-- The Cell

```
public partial class MyCollectionViewCell : MvxCollectionViewCell {    
        public MyCollectionViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            BindUrl();
        }
        public void BindUrl()
        {
            this.ClearAllBindings ();
            this.DelayBind(() => {
                this.CreateBinding(MyWebView)
                    .For(webView => webView.MyUrl)
                    .To<ListItemViewModel>(vm => vm.UrlEntryPoint)
                    .Apply();
          });
}
```

Comment: IMO this question really needs code included. Overriding `GetOrCreateCellFor` does not normally stop binding working - I've done this plenty of times. However, the devil is in the detail. How are you doing what you are doing? How can readers of this question guess that?

Comment: @Stuart I've added the missing code.

Comment: Why are you calling `cellz.ClearAllBindings ();` - that removes all Data Bindings

Comment: I remove all the previous bindings of the Cell and recreate it. I also tried with `cellz.ClearAllBindings ()` commented, and it's still the same :-(

Comment: Maybe start from something that works - e.g. http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n11-collectionview-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html - and see if you can spot what is causing your issues... Currently it feels like you have several extra bits of code that neither of us is sure why they've been added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help in this.

I'm also using Storyboards instead of XIB. I'll see if XIBs make any difference.

Is there a way to create a new cell every time `GetOrCreateCellFor` is called? I can't seem to figure out how to provide a handle to the IntPtr param `var cell = new MyCollectionViewCell (new IntPtr());`

Comment: I think you **really** need to understand what the `IntPtr` is for - very much worth reading up in the MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS documentation. You can't just invent your own `IntPtr`!

Comment: Thanks again, I'm suspecting this is a case of PEBKAC.

I guess I need to talk to my rubber duck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've solved this issue by mixing couple of strategies.

1. Created a `SelectedItemNo` property in the DataSource
2. In the Delegate method `DecelerationEnded` I calculated the current index of the cell and change the **CollectionView.SelectedItemNo** property to match the current visible cell.